# jmeter webdriver not picking up vars values

Tags: selenium, jmeter

I'm a little confused with jmeter at the moment when using selenium

I have two webdriver samplers for two different pages.

I also have a JSR223 Sampler which I'm using to set up data - for example

`vars.put("loanAmount", "50000");`

along with some other variables.

When I hit the first webdriver sampler I am able to access any of the vars with vars.get("value");

However, in the second webdriver sampler, if i try to access vars.get nothing happens. Nothing is written to the log etc

I've added in some debug lines, and when I run

`WDS.log.info ('********** loanAmount ' + vars.get("loanAmount")+ ' ***********');`

it just falls over.

its the same if i try to use sendKeys with the var too, so I'm assuming that it can't access vars

Do i need to do something to make the vars available across all samplers?

Comment: ha ha it certainly does. The second sampler was missing var vars = org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterContextService.getContext().getVariables() Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have `vars` defined in the WebDriver sampler, you need to use `WDS.vars` instead, it has the same syntax as it's basically a shorthand for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance

[image]

You can find more WebDriver Sampler tips and tricks in [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article

Comment: it worked with just using vars. I'll have a look to see what is different between vars and wds.vars